# Put data in CSV - column by column - in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

7 on Windows 7 system.
I already opened a csv file and got some data.
My goal is to put the data in the csv file column by column.

Here is my code:

```
log = open("C:\Logging\\" + date + '_' + second + "logData.csv", 'ab')
log.write('test1')
log.write('test2')
log.write('test3')
log.write('test4')
log.write('test5')
```

...some other code...

```
log.write('test6')
log.write('test7')
```

How to put test1, test2...test7 in different columns (column by column)?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.

Comment: Specifically, show us some sample input data, the output form you want, *and your best attempt to code the solution*.  So far, all you've done is to write header labels.

Comment: In general, you cannot write a file column by column; you have to assemble rows and write in that order.

Answer (score 0):

Use the csv library

```
import csv

with open("C:\Logging\\" + date + '_' + second + "logData.csv", 'ab') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(('Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3'))
```

To do some other code in between some of the writes:

```
row = ['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3', 'Test4', 'Test5']
# Do some other code here
row += ['Test6', 'Test7']

with open("C:\Logging\\" + date + '_' + second + "logData.csv", 'ab') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for the first three tests. But how to append the next two tests to the following two columns~?

Comment: Add more strings to that line, each new item will be in a new column: `writer.writerow(('Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3', 'Test4', 'Test5', 'Test6', 'Test7', 'Test8'))`

Comment: yea, but test 1-5 and test 6-7 are interrupted by some other code, so I am wondering how to append them all...

Comment: You mean that you are writing 1-5, then doing something else and then writing 6-7? Can you do that other thing first and then write 1-7? Otherwise you can do it with lists and then write them all when it's done, I'll update the answer with that code ^

Comment: Thanks @olofom, what is in my code is, the csv file is for testing result. So I run my first test and put the test result in the csv file column by column, like 'test1, pass '. Then I run the following code for the next test, and put 'test2, fail' next to 'test1, pass'.

Comment: Then I think that building lists with your data and writing them to csv when they're done seems like a reasonable solution, especially if you want multiple data on the same row generated at different times.

Comment: could you please enlighten me about the 'list' idea?

Comment: As per the second example in my answer to you. There I created a list, called "row", where I add some strings. Then some other code happens, and then I add more to the row list. In the end I write the entire list to the csv file. Each item in the list will end up in a new column in the csv file.

Comment: It works! Smart cookie! BTW, do you have any idea to remove a set of data (in one column) to one row?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with removing a set of data in a column to a row?

Comment: rearrange/transpose the data (from one column) to one row~ :)